# VBA-PIVOT TABLE WIZARD METHOD

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I am trying to create a macro to build pivottable using the code at the following website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh243933.aspx

but I kept getting

> Error 1004: "UNABLE TO GET THE PIVOTFIELDS PROPERTY OF THE PIVOT TABLE
>   CLASS"

Any suggestions on the reason behind this problem and possible ways to fix it?

**THIS IS MY CODE**:

```
Sub CreatePivot()

' Creates a PivotTable report from the table on Sheet1
' by using the PivotTableWizard method with the PivotFields
' method to specify the fields in the PivotTable.

Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField

' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data.
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A2").Select

' Create the PivotTable object based on the Employee data on Sheet1.
Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard

' Specify row and column fields.
***Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("v1")*** ' <-- This where I get the Error
objField.Orientation = xlColumnField

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Temperature")
objField.Orientation = xlRowField

' Specify a data field with its summary
' function and format.
Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("clkui")
objField.Orientation = xlDataField
objField.Function = xlSum
objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"

' Specify a page field.
Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("db")
objField.Orientation = xlPageField

' Preview the new PivotTable report.
ActiveSheet.PrintPreview

' Prompt the user whether to delete the PivotTable.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If MsgBox("Delete the PivotTable?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    ActiveSheet.Delete
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oSlE.png)

Comment: is the `PivotTable` already created in "Sheet1" ? or not ? where does the data for the `PivotTable` lies ? which Sheet ? Range ?

Comment: no.the pivottable not created.the data is in sheet1

Comment: try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to create a new table in `Sheet1` (not sure what's the sheet's name) from the data in "Sheet1" :

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePivot()

' Creates a PivotTable report from the table on Sheet1
' by using the PivotTableWizard method with the PivotFields
' method to specify the fields in the PivotTable.

Dim objTable As PivotTable
Dim objTblCache As PivotCache
Dim objField As PivotField
Dim PvtSht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim SrcRng  As Range

' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set SrcRng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)) ' <-- set the Pivot's dynamic Range (starts from "A2")
End With

' Option 1: Define Pivot Cache
Set objTblCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, SrcRng)

' Option 2: Define Pivot Cache
Set objTblCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, True))

' Create the PivotTable object based on the Employee data on Sheet1.
Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=objTblCache, TableDestination:=Sheet1.Cells(1, LastCol + 2), TableName:="PivotTable1")

' Specify row and column fields.
With objTable
    .PivotFields("v1").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotFields("Temperature").Orientation = xlRowField

    ' Specify a data field with its summary
    ' function and format.
    Set objField = .PivotFields("clkui")
    With objField
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"
    End With

    ' Specify a page field.
    .PivotFields("db").Orientation = xlPageField
End With

' rest of your code goes here ....


End Sub
```

Comment: I realized there are tow ways to create pivottable:1.with PivotTableWizard method .2. with Pivot Cache.

Comment: I realized there are tow ways to create pivottable:1.with PivotTableWizard method .2. with Pivot Cache.    i want to do this with pivot table wizard. the line "Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard" is working so pivot is created but its get stack in "Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("v1")" in my code

Comment: @ofir I have never used your way in VBA (so far I haven't encountered a single attempt of using it here on **SO**)

Comment: ok. very good. i have  anather  question: how i remove subtotal option from the pivot table